# Four forces acting along the side of a quadrilateral

Tags: vectors

ABCD is a quadrilateral. forces k.AB , l.CB, m.CD , n,AD  acting along the side AB, CB,CD,AD are equilibrium. prove that km=ln . How can I prove that?

[image]

Comment: Provide a graphical representation, please.

Comment: can you please try to draw with pen and papers.

Comment: Your problem, as written, is not understandable. It is your interest to provide a figure : in 2018, you have so many tools for drawing and it is so easy to include them that it is a neglected attitude towards us not to do it.

Comment: can you please understand now? please help . @Jean Marie

Comment: Thanks for the effort of drawing a figure. You understand surely that, calling $O$ the rectangle's center, you have to write an equality of **moments** with respect to $O$ ; for example the moment of the force exerted along side $AB$ is $\dfrac{n}{2} \times k$ or  $\dfrac{n}{2} \times k.AB$  where $\dfrac{n}{2}$ is the distance of side $AB$ to the origin. You do this for the 3 other forces, add them  (taking care of the signs), and express that equilibrium is obtained when this sum is $0$  and you will get your result...

Comment: Its  not rectangle. its a quadrilateral. Sorry for the drawing as rectangle. It can be any kind of quadrilateral

Comment: In this case, as there is no "all-purpose" center in a general quadrilateral, I don't know what to advise you... (a quadrilateral has at least two different centers : the center of gravity and the intersection of diagonals which are distinct points in general).